# How to silence warnings

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a class that inherits from a another class.
I am overloading one method; PHP screams about this.
How do I silence this message? It clutters my debug logs.

> Declaration of
>   Dashboard_Abstract::factory() should
>   be compatible with that of
>   Abstract::factory()

```
class Abstract{
  static public function factory($param){
  ...
  ...
  }
}


class Dashboard_Abstract extends Abstract{
  static public function factory($param1,$param2){
  ...
  ...
  }
}
```

Look, fellow developers. There is a difference between errors and warnings:
means,

> "Look, if you are new to this you
>   might be doing something wrong here,
>   If you are experienced, you might be
>   doing right, so we will let you, the
>   developer, decide."

So, why won't you let me decide?
Is it so bad to use all of a language abilities to the max, even if some think it is an error (although, obviously, it is not).

Comment: By fixing the problem :P

Comment: is that a warning or a flat out error?

Comment: Cure the cause instead of trying to ignore the symptoms.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994758/function-overloading-and-overriding-in-php

Comment: @Neal  , it is not an error, just a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function to override it at runtime, and there's an identically named parameter in php.ini you can set to make the change permanent. However, warnings are there for a reason and generally you should fix your code instead of just silencing them.

Comment: +1 for first answering the OPs question and recommend fixing thereafter.

Comment: It seems to me there is a good reason this is a warning only and not error - means, "Look, if you are new to this you **might** be doing something wrong here, If you are experienced, you might be doing right, so we will let **you** the developer decide."

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it is a specialized class, altering the method signature should not trigger a warning. It doesn't in pure OOP languages. And E_STRICT is really a special kind of purposed warning message (trying to impose a non-semantic coding standard).

But anyway, there is an easy workaround for your case. You can make the method signature compatible by just making parameters optional in the overriding method:

```
class Abc {
  static public function factory($param) { }
}  

class Xyz extends Abc {
  static public function factory($param1, $param2=NULL) { }
}
```

Notice the `$param2=NULL` in the overloading method signature. With this trick the more specialized class/object can still be used where a parent object was expected.
You might use an `assert($param2!==NULL)` within the method instead if it is required.

(The E_STRICT notice for eventually undefined parameters in your static factory methods -which are only ever used with explicit classnames- really makes no sense here. But won't get fixed http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41461 in the php.net implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not overriding it correctly because the number of variables has changed. It will continue to yell at you about this, as it should. Keep the number of arguments the same, use default arguments if you have to.

Comment: Yes but PHP thinks you're overriding

Comment: I want the computer to do what I want, not do what he wants me to :-D If I need to go into the internals for this, I will :-)

Comment: Yeah well "do as a say" rarely works, it's best to see things from the languages point of view.

Comment: some times you have to bend the rules. I thought this very carefully, weather I should use a different tree structure of the inheritance, and the simplicity of my solution is much better then  the added complexity of a huge tree of abstract classes, just to silence a single warning. I hope I am enough time in this to smartly know when you can/should bend the "rules" and when not.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the problem.  If you have a child class overriding a method in a parent class, the signature of the method must be compatible.  That means that it must have the same or greater visibility, the same staticity (?!) and the same number or fewer arguments.

Either `Abstract` should take two parameters, or `Dashboard_Abstract` should take one. I can't tell you which way round it should be without seeing what these classes actually do...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't silence that message, instead you should make sure that the overriding method is compatible with the original one. If you need the overriding method to accept a different number of parameters, you could rewrite the original method to use a dynamic list of arguments - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php