# Is the term function overloading equivalent to method overloading in Java?

Tags: java

I recently took an online test for an interview. It was a multiple choice test and I got the following question:

> Q) In a Java class we can write multiple methods with same name and 
>   different method signatures, this is called_____________
>
> a) function overriding
>   b) function overloading
>   c) none of the above

I know that it is method overloading but in the options it's not there

Is the term function overloading equivalent to method overloading in Java?

Comment: Method and function are sometimes used interchangeably in Java. Method is the correct term.

Comment: java has no functions. that's just a test made up by someone who doesn't really know Java all that well, and assumes that function and method are synonyms

Comment: Ain't no functions in Java.

Comment: @nicomp Only `Function`s?

Comment: @bcsb1001 No, they're not. A function is a named piece of code that is not encapsulated in an class.  That's not possible in Java.

Comment: It really doesn't matter according to me. We call it a method in java, function in C, I guess.

Comment: @shmosel no functions in Java, no Functions in Java.

Comment: @nicomp [Are you sure?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)

Comment: @nicomp Actually, there are both `Function`s and `Method`s.

Comment: @shmosel Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, @shmosel, can you really believe Oracle's Javadoc?

Comment: From a math perspective, aren't methods just sugary functions?  To me it seems like this is arguing **really** strict semantics.  I guess the "none of the above" opens the door for this being a trick question, but I wouldn't want to work for a company that wants to get this petty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pragmatic point of view, I would go with function overloading.

But when thinking in pure Java terms, the one and only term is methods. Java does not know functions, only methods. Besides the interface Function.

Coming from there, it is not really clear if "none" or "function overloading" is the correct answer.

Comment: Fine explanation. It seems that some C++ users invert method and function.  For example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912022/differentiate-between-function-overloading-and-function-overriding