# Overloading virtual method in derived class with different signature

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual

Having

- a BASE class defining a virtual method
- a DERIVED class which defines a virtual method with the same name, but different signature

the compiler complains that it cannot find the correct function in the BASE class when called from another class using a pointer to the DERIVED class.

**Example (Constructors etc omitted):**

```
class BASE {
    public: virtual int print(std::vector<double>& values);
};

int BASE::print(std::vector<double>& values){
    std::cout << "This is the base class!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
class DERIVED : public BASE {
    public: void virtual print(int a, int b);
};

void DERIVED::print(int a, int b){
    std::cout << "This is the derived class from int-method!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
class TEST {
    public: void testit();
};

void TEST::testit(){
    DERIVED derived;
    std::vector<double> a;
    derived.print(a);
}
```

The compiler complains with `TEST.cpp:30:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘DERIVED::print(std::vector<double>&)`

What can I do to overload virtual functions with different signatures in derived classes? For example, this may be useful to add functionality that cannot be available in the BASE class.

Comment: To override functions they need to have the exact same signature.

Comment: I suppose you mean override, not overload. You cannot override a method with a different signature.

Comment: if you actually mean overload, please include a [mcve] and the complete error message in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912022/differentiate-between-function-overloading-and-function-overriding

Comment: None of those functions are public, so neither `print` variant is available for `Test::testit` to call.

Comment: Can you make the functions `public` then try?

Comment: Technically what you are doing is overloading, not overriding the inherited function.    You're running into the "hiding rule".   For `DERIVED` to be able to use both the inherited `print()` and the `print()` it supplies, add a `using BASE::print()` to the definition of `DERIVED`.     The two function are distinct though - one won't magically call the other, unless you write code explicitly to make that happen.   And, unless `TESTIT` is a `friend` of `BASE` and/or `DERIVED`, it cannot call `private` member functions of them.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Apparently, there was some confusion on my side about the terms 'overriding' and 'overloading'. I meant 'overloading', and have adjusted the question. @Peter and @HolyBlackCat answered the question: I was not aware the `print()` will be hidden even when it has a different signature.

Comment: @idclev What is missing for a minimal reproducible example? The error message is given in the text - is there a standardized way of doing that here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` in the `DERIVED` shadows `print` in the `BASE`, even though the signatures are different.

To fix, add `using BASE::print;` to the `DERIVED`. Note that this line can change the access modifier of the inherited function; if you want the function to be `public`, the `using ...` must also be `public`.

Be aware that you don't override any functions here ([usually](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Covariant_return_types) that's only possible if signatures are same). You create two unrelated functions with the same name. This means `virtual` can be removed, unless you plan to add more derived classes and actually override functions in them.

Comment: Thanks - got it! Adding `public: using BASE::print;` to the DERIVED class did the job! So what is the logics behind hiding/shadowing all methods of the BASE class when overloading these methods in a derived class? I assume there would be no ambiguity in not doing so ?!?

Comment: @sputn1k Probably that was done to make sure you can safely add new methods to a base class, without worrying about derived classes silently changing behavior if they has methods with the same name.