# How a PHP function understands the value to put into the variables accordingly?

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

For one of my WordPress site, I want to make a broad custom PHP function with many variables and some of them are with ease as optional like:

```
<?php    
function customFunction( $variable1, $variable2 = null, $variable3, $variable4 ) {
       if ( !$variable1 == null ) { echo 'something'; } else { echo $variable1; }
       if ( !$variable2 == null ) { echo 'something more'; } else { echo $variable2; }
       if ( !$variable3 == null ) { echo 'something else'; } else { echo $variable3; }
       if ( !$variable4 == null ) { echo 'something other than this'; } else { echo $variable4; }
    return $variable1;
    return $variable2;
    return $variable3;
    return $variable4;
    }
?>
```

Please note that, the `$variable2` is optional and contains a default `NULL` value.

Now if I use the function like:

```
<?php customFunction( '1', '2', '3', '4' ); ?>
```

Then it will understand to put the figures according to the serial of the variables in the function like:

```
$variable1 = 1;
$variable2 = 2;
$variable3 = 3;
$variable4 = 4;
```

But as the `$variable2` is optional, if I ***skip it*** then what would be the result? I guess:

```
<?php customFunction( '1', '3', '4' ); ?>

$variable1 = 1;
$variable2 = 3;
$variable3 = 4;
### ERROR ###
```

Am I right? or, the thing is something else?

If I'm right, then
**What would be the right way to make a function or sort a function with mandatory and optional values?**

Comment: Oops! That's not the issue. But thanks. I made them just instantly. Please be on the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to call it like this

```
<?php customFunction( '1','', '3', '4' ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php customFunction( '1', , '3', '4' ); ?>
```

You have a fixed/static input list so the function requires the same incoming arg count only the final one in the arg list can be totally omitted.  You could also pass in an array as others have suggested.

Also you can't return multiple items like this

```
return $variable1;
return $variable2;
return $variable3;
return $variable4;
```

You would have to return an array of items like this

```
return array("Var1" => $variable1,"Var2" => $variable2,"Var3" => $variable3,"Var4" => $variable4);
```

and so if you did `$functionoutput = customFunction( '1', '2', '3', '4' );`
Then you could access the return like below

```
echo $functionoutput['Var1'];
echo $functionoutput['Var2'];
echo $functionoutput['Var3'];
echo $functionoutput['Var4'];
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a similar function with different parameters, then you are looking for overloading. See on this link.

[What is function overloading and overriding in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994758/what-is-function-overloading-and-overriding-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your parameters are invalid. It is not allowed to have optional parameters before non-optional ones.
2. To solve your problem, I would recommend using an array as parameter & check its items.

Comment: I don't think it's _invalid_ as such, I think you are _allowed_ to add non-optional params after an optional param, but it defeats the point, because you'll have to pass the optional parameter to the function either way...