# Remove wordpress action inside class definition function of a theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need help in removing the action of wordpress within a public function of class.
I want to remove OLD function and want to define a new function against it.

Code looks like below

```
function hook_link($c){ return  apply_filters('hook_link', $c);  }

class blue_themes {

    public function blue_themes(){

        add_action( 'hook_link', array($this, 'OLD') );

        function OLD($val){ //want to remove this action

           return $val;

        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redefine Class Methods or Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137006/redefine-class-methods-or-class)

Comment: OR...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994758/what-is-function-overloading-and-overriding-in-php

Comment: Can you please provide me a solution

Answer (score -1):

use this function for remove old function and add new function .

```
remove_filter('remove function name', 1);
add_filter('add function name', 1);
```