# Missing downcast argument solution in PHP

Tags: php

Imagine a generic library defines a class:

```
class A_CLASS {
    public function foo(B_CLASS $b) {
        // Use $b as B_CLASS
    }
}
class B_CLASS {
}
```

And I need to override this one, but with my own child B_CLASS, so I would declare

```
class A_CHILD_CLASS extends A_CLASS {
    public function foo(B_CHILD_CLASS $b) {
        parent::foo($b);
        // Use $b as B_CHILD_CLASS
    }
}
class B_CHILD_CLASS extends B_CLASS {
}
```

This is not working on PHP 5.6.
In other languages, this will work, and we could also use a generic interface.
But in PHP, this is not available and there is no generic interface.

So, how could I implement it in PHP ?
This is really a problem in my project.

Comment: Not working __how__?

Comment: If i use this source, I get "Declaration of A_CHILD_CLASS::foo() should be compatible with A_CLASS::foo(B_CLASS $b)"

Comment: So, modify declaration

Comment: For what class ? B_CLASS does not implements required methods.

Comment: But as class `B_CHILD_CLASS` extends `B_CLASS` it can also be considered as argument of type `B_CLASS`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error:

> Declaration of A_CHILD_CLASS::foo() should be compatible with A_CLASS::foo(B_CLASS $b)

is that you are trying to override the `foo()` function **but** with different arguments. As far as I know this is called overloading which isn't supported by PHP. (while there are some [patches to bypass it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php))

Therefore, the solution should be to modify this function:

```
public function foo(B_CHILD_CLASS $b)
```

To:

```
public function foo(B_CLASS $b)
```

And to find a different way to achieve what's you're looking for.
Consider removing the declaration of the argument's type.

```
public function foo($b)
```

**Further reading:**

- [Declaration of Methods should be Compatible with Parent Methods in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115388/declaration-of-methods-should-be-compatible-with-parent-methods-in-php)
- [What is function overloading and overriding in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994758/what-is-function-overloading-and-overriding-in-php)

Comment: Yes, I know but I hoped for a better solution :D